# How to subset lists after split

Tags: r, list

I have split a dataframe,based on a column.

The resulting list of dataframes includes some that have less than one row. I would like to only include those dataframes that have more than 5 rows in my list. How can I do this?

I have tried `lapply(mylst,mylst[nrow>5])` but its a flat fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `sapply` to get the number of rows (`nrow`) as a `vector`, convert to a logical vector with `>5` and use that to subset the `list`.

```
mylst[sapply(mylst, nrow)>5]
```

Or use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x)>5, mylst)
```